# Android, Data Output Stream, Out of memory

Tags: android, io

I am using this segment of copy a large file. Android crashes with "out of memory" at exactly 32 buffer loads. It is acting like dos.write is putting the data into a large  buffer rather than spooling it out to the i/o device. No exception is thrown.

The bufferSize = 512*1024. bis is a BufferedInputStream. byteArray is a ByteArrayBuffer,

```
        try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        int current = 0;

        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
            byteArray.append((byte)current);
            if (byteArray.isFull()){
                byte[] b = byteArray.toByteArray();
                dos.write(b, 0, bufferSize);
                byteArray.clear();
                }
            }

        int count = byteArray.length();
        byte[] b = byteArray.toByteArray();
        dos.write(b, 0, count);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            bis.close();
       }
         catch (Exception e) {
         RunTimeError("Exception: " + e);
         return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that `byteArray.isFull()` is always returning `false` for some reason. Then when you have loaded 16MB of data, you're out of memory. I wouldn't bother with a `ByteArrayBuffer`. (For that matter, 512KB is way too large a buffer for this kind of operation. You should try to match the file I/O block size. It probably varies by device, but 4K-8K is probably close.) You also don't need to wrap `fos` in a `DataOutputStream`; you're just writing bytes. A `BufferedOutputStream`, on the other hand, might be useful. And if `bis` is not buffered, wrapping it in a `BufferedInputStream` will also help.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
try {
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), 8192);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int len = 0;

    while((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
     RunTimeError("Exception: " + e);
     return false;
} finally {
    try { bis.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) { }
    try { bos.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) { }
}
```

Comment: @Ted Hopp May I have a question? Why can't we just add `dos.flush()` after `dos.write()`. Each time the dos write bytes to the buffer, `dos.flush()` flushes the target stream. (As I know from the document) The `OutOfMemoryError` exception is still throwed by `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: @Stallman - OP's code didn't use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`; `dos` was directed to a `FileOutputStream`. In any event, the `OutOfMemoryError` was, I think, caused by the `ByteArrayBuffer` never reporting that it was full, not by the writes to `dos`.